# App Crashes on IPad 2 build in XCode 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have made a text editor app in XCode 4.0. It's working fine on iPad 1 but not working on iPad 2. When i try to load it on iPad 2 it show a black screen and just exits.

Comment: can edit your question, please append the gdb console error message.

Comment: Actually i don't have IPad 2. I send the Adhoc  IPA File but not working in his IPad 2

Comment: Ask the iPad2 owner to supply you with the LOG file. He may get it off the device conveniently by using the iPhone Configuration Utility downloadable from Apple's site.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the remote device has the correct provisioning profile installed

Comment: There is no provisioning profile problem. if there is that kind problem application will not be installed on IPad. It will show the Code Signing Problem while syncing with itues

Answer (score 0):

Check these:
 - Do you have a developer account?

- Have you created App Profile on iOS
  provisioning portal?
- The iPad2 is in  the devices list In the iOS
  provisioning Portal?
- Have you send
  the monileprovision to the adhoc
  tester?
- The mobile monileprovision
  contains the iPad2 device?

Comment: Yes i have developer account. The Problem happens when i build the project with XCode 4.0. but when build it with XCode 3.2.5 it works fine. And i m sure that there is no provisioning problem

Comment: I have the same problem when switched, i renew my developer certificate, and added my new profile to the development profiles (eg. turn the checkboxes on).

Comment: But in case of provisioning profile problem itunes will not allow to install the app on ipad so i think that there is no problem with the provisioning profile..

Comment: No warnings in the code? What is your deployment target in build settings?

Comment: No Warning coming. deployment target is 4.3 and its working fine in my IPad 1

Comment: is there any settings in xcode related to ipad device ? other than Deployment target .

Comment: The first stock of iPad2 comes width 4.2, and if your tester don't updated. You use 4.3 specific code in your app? If not, your deployment target can be, 4.2 or a little bit lower (i use 4.0 in iPhone and 4.2 in iPad)...